# Gif shared through UIActivityViewController comes out as static image in (at least) fb, twitter, notes

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share a gif from my (unity) app, through the standard iOS sharing screen, to a social network.

Because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546455/ios-share-gifs-to-messenger-using-uiactivityviewcontroller?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I first wrap the path to the gif in an NSURL before sending it to the UIActivityViewController:

```
NSURL *nsGifURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:nsGifPath];
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[nsMessage, nsGifURL];

// find the unity window:
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIActivityViewController *share = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[window.rootViewController presentViewController:share animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This all compiles and runs without errors, but when I reach the other app, the image is static and not a gif.

How do I make apps like fb accept and display a gif on the other end?

EDIT: the nsGifPath definitely has the .gif extension

Comment: I've also tried passing an NSData of the gif, to the same static-image result. The NSExtensionItem dumps some info about the object, and correctly identifies it as a com.compuserve.gif.

Comment: check this similar questions having good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623931/how-to-share-an-gif-animated-images-in-ios

Comment: read the data and try to use this function as extension for data, 
`var format: String {
        let array = [UInt8](self)
        let ext: String
        switch array[0] {
        case 0xFF:
            ext = "jpg"
        case 0x89:
            ext = "png"
        case 0x47:
            ext = "gif"
        case 0x4d:
            ext = "tiff"
        default:
            ext = "unknown"
        }
        return ext
    }`
What do you get as result?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what "use as extension for data" means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007067/ios-share-gif-animated-image-not-working) answer you have to consider separated ways for social networks

> TWITTER : For share a GIF on twitter had to use twitter API and create a multipart request to achieve the goal and its working very
>   well.
>
> FACEBOOK : I did share some GIF on Facebook using FACEBOOKSHAREKIT ,
>   but i don't know why sometimes Gifs are animated, sometimes not.
>
> INSTAGRAM : To share gif on Instagram had to convert GIFS to MP4 (or
>   any other video formats accepted by Instagram) then save it into
>   camera roll then share it , It is little twisted but its working very
>   well.
>
> WHATSAPP : It not supporting GIF at all.
>
> To do all of this i couldn't use "UIActivityViewController" , so
>   decided to create a custom share page. if anybody know something to
>   add here , to help me and others please tell me (especially about
>   Facebook). Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I'd rather not support gifs at all than integrate and support all these SDKs and workflows. Come on iOS, this works great on android...